# Android: Error implementing listview within fragment

Tags: android

I created an android actionbar tab application, with 4 tabs, one of the tab is a 
fragment class which is used to contain a list view,to display a list of static information:

However, I have an error at this line of code:
     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,

```
 R.layout.listoflockers, from, to);
```

These are my 2 xml files used to create a list view:

```
 listoflockers.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>


lockerinforow.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/email"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
 />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
    />
       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


  public class myLockerFragment.java{
   .....

      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mylocker, container,    false);



        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

             ();        

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
              HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

            hm.put("txt", "Locker No : " + i);

            hm.put("cur","Location : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("size","Size : " + size[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur","size" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur,R.id.size};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, 

            R.layout.listoflockers, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return rootView;
      }
```

Please help
I am confused at this line:

```
   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, 
   R.layout.listoflockers, from, to);
```

giving me the error:
The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type myLockerFragment

Answer (score 3):

you can use `getActivity()` inside a `Fragment` to get the context that holds the Fragment itself

Answer (score 0):

Do this-

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, 
   R.layout.listoflockers, from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), aList, R.layout.listoflockeres, from, to);
```

You need to use the `getActivity()` method inside `Fragments`

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `getBaseContext()` you need to use the `getActivity()` in `Fragments` to get the context of the Fragment.

Try out as below:

```
  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList,R.layout.listoflockers, from, to);
```